# ajax no recibe valores FormData

Tags: php, ajax, formdata

Tengo un formulario modal desde el quiero enviar los datos por ajax a otro archivo y allí ejecutar la sentencia sql. El problema es que no consigo que me envie la información al archivo.

botón del formulario

```javascript
     $("#btnGuardar").on('click',function(){

            var nomempleado =$("#txtnombreempleado").val(),
                apellido1 =$("#txtprimerapellido").val(),
                apellido2 =$("#txtsegundoapellido").val();
                
            var datos= new FormData();

            datos.append('nomempleado',nomempleado);
            datos.append('apellido1', apellido1);
            datos.append('apellido2',apellido2);

            $.ajax({
                "url": "ajax/empleados.ajax.php",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataSrc": "",
                "data":datos,//carga datos
                "cache":false,
                "contentype":false,
                "processData": false,
                "sucess": function (respuesta){
                    console.log(respuesta);
                    $("#modal-gestionar-empleado").modal('hide');
                    table.ajax.reload(null,false);
                }
            });
    })
```

y lo intento recuperar asi:

```php
if (isset($_Post['empleado']) ){
   $empl = $_POST['empleado'];
   echo $empl;
} else {
   echo "No recibi ningun dato";
}
```

Comment: En el php buscas por "empleado" y eso no lo estas enviando .  Estas enviando nomempleado, apellido1 y apellido2

Comment: Además, es _success_, no _sucess_.

Comment: Además, escribe siempre el nombre de las superglobales en mayúscula:  `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc. Los nombres de variable son *case sensitive* en PHP, de modo que `$_POST` no es lo mismo que `$_Post`. Tendrás derecho a un *`Undefined variable`* en tu código.

Comment: Voto por cerrar tiene muchos errores tipograficos

Comment: Ademas recomendaria el uso de Eventos Delegados con `jquery` con `document` como base.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

Toma los datos con Jquery un poco más sencilla. Claro que acá falta más que trabajes (validaciones, seguridad, base de datos).

1. El formulario debe contener los siguientes campos:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Formulario</h2>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
            <label for="txtnombreempleado">Nombre empleado:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="txtnombreempleado" name="nomempleado"><br>
            <label for="txtprimerapellido">Apellido 1:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="txtprimerapellido" name="apellido1"><br><br>
            <label for="txtsegundoapellido">Apellido 2:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="txtsegundoapellido" name="apellido2"><br><br>
            <input id="btnGuardar" type="button" value="Guardar">
        </form> 
        <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

2. Luego el Jquery

   ```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#btnGuardar").on('click', function () {
     var data = {
        "nomempleado": $("#txtnombreempleado").val(),
        "apellido1": $("#txtprimerapellido").val(),
        "apellido2": $("#txtsegundoapellido").val()
    };
    $.ajax({

        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax/empleados.ajax.php',

        beforeSend: function () {
            console.log("Esperando...");
        },
        success: function (respuesta)            {
            console.log("Respuesta: " + respuesta);
            $("#modal-gestionar-empleado").modal('hide');
            table.ajax.reload(null, false);
         }
       });
     });
   });
   ```
3. El procesar:

   ```
    $nomempleado = $apellido1 = $apellido2 = "";

     if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      $nomempleado = $_POST["nomempleado"];
      $apellido1 = $_POST["apellido1"];
      $apellido2 = $_POST["apellido2"];
     echo "resultado: " . $nomempleado . " " . $apellido1 . " " . $apellido2;
     } else {
      echo "No recibí ningún dato";
    }
   ```

Comment: Lo primero de todo muchas gracias a todos por contestar.  Me ha funcionado correctamente. Ahora solo me hace falta que me cierre la ventana ya que no me hace caso el $("#modal-gestionar-empleado").modal('hide');

Comment: Formula una nueva pregunta, mostrando lo que has hecho.